# How to convert HTML page to image format in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

How to convert HTML page to image format in a web application?

Comment: Can you give a little more information? 
Like what browser you'd like to see it in?
Are you writing an ASP.NET web application, or trying to create images of one?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to be able to create an image out of a web page dynamically in an ASP.NET application, you can try using [ABC PDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm).  We've had really good luck using their product and it is pretty reasonable.  You can save html/web pages as PDF's, JPEGs, and a host of other file formats.