# export in pdf report

Tags: asp.net, reporting, export-to-pdf

I have a web report(.aspx page).  I like to have a functionality to export that report into pdf format.  Is there any way I can export it to PDF format without using any third party control or product?

Or any other way I can use report viewer control's export feature in web page and hiding report viewer control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Export to PDF**

Yes, you can do it, but I think this would be highly inefficient and possibly difficult and time consuming. In a nutshell, you would be writing your own "to PDF" library - just like the ones that already exist, so, why reinvent the wheel?

If you are willing to use a third party control (some of them are free, or even open source), you have some better options:

- [using Visual Studio's Crystal Reports](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4266/how-to-create-pdf-files-from-aspnet-pages/) (you asked about this in your second paragraph)
- [using free 3rd party itextsharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Creating_PDF_documents_in.aspx)
- [using any other free (or not) library](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net+to+pdf)

If you are still not willing to use a third party control, and don't want to create the library yourself, you have some other odd options :

- Have your client "print" the page to their installed PDF printer (like CutePDF)
- Convert the page into an image, and from there into a PDF

Comment: how to convert the page to an image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280817/how-to-convert-html-web-page-to-image-format-in-asp-net-web-application